# Wifi Adapter Stops Working After Ubuntu 18.04 Update

Tags: 18.04

I just updated to Ubuntu 18.04 and my WiFi adapter has stopped working. I have had problems with it before when I first installed Ubuntu 14.04. I can get internet through Ethernet so no problem there. Secure boot is off.
The output for `sudo lshw -C network` is

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:91100000-9110ffff
   *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 15
   serial: ac:e2:d3:d4:91:14
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.86.248 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:117 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:91004000-91004fff memory:91000000-91003fff
```

The output for `nmcli device show` is

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         AC:E2:D3:D4:91:14
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveCo
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.86.248/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.86.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.86.1, mt =
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.86.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt 
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt =
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.86.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          lan
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::ed6a:4eda:3f8d:c52e/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

Thank you

Nyle

Comment: Need more info. `sudo lshw -C network` and `nmcli device show` would be useful.

Comment: Changed it as you said.

Comment: Well that's interesting. It looks like your wireless hasn't been set up as there's no entry for it at all in `nmcli device show`, which there should be, even if you were connected via ethernet cable as you are.  There's no MAC address of your wireless device either. Can you also print output (last one) of `nmcli connection show`?

Comment: @PaulBenson: I don't find that interesting at all considering that the wireless network adapter is unclaimed by any driver.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0280]'; rfkill list`? Thanks.